# Is the site name IT-Security, or App-Security?

Tags: discussion

Cuz the site is not fully consistent... Most places its "Application Security", as it was in the Area51 proposal, but the logo, the domain name, and the notification email, its IT security.

My vote is to keep this AppSec focused, thats wide enough, though I might understand why @Robert would want to merge them. On the other hand, it's crystal clear that SO could not have included SF - completely different worlds...

Answer (score 9):

It is **IT Security**, as we combined a few proposals to get here:

[What is the difference between the Security proposals on Area51? Should they be merged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67584/what-is-the-difference-between-the-security-proposals-on-area51-should-they-be-m)

Comment: Sorry I missed that discussion the first time around, as I mentioned these are really very different fields, with only rarely shared terminology, formulas, methodologies, problems, and solutions. I'm still against merging them (though I do understand why from outside the field you'd want to merge them). I think this is similar to the Linux/Ubuntu debacle... :)

Comment: And @Jeff, **if** we are going the way of merging all security-related topics into one mega-security site, then you should probably also merge http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4500/infosec-and-risk-management, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14373/php-specific-security-issues-and-best-practices, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18054/white-hat-hacking, and probably http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography

Comment: (there was also one on SIEM/security event monitoring, but i cant find it now)

Comment: @avid I closed a few but the latter two don't seem so overlappy to me

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I wasnt sure about those two - to me, "code review" is *almost* synonymous with "security code review", but I guess its not for *normal* people. Wrt cryptography, to me crypto *is* part of security, but on the other hand expert cryptographers pretty much define themselves as a completely seperate group.

Answer (score 3):

**Buffer Overflow**

Comment: Or **Stack smashing**

Comment: @Graham Lee Or Security Suspicions

Comment: +1 for Buffer Overflow as the final site's name.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, I tend to see IT Security as a wholly enclosed and dependent subset of Information Security. As you can see from some of the answers even on this site, it is evident that the People, Process and Technology areas of security are quite difficult to separate.

I think it is right that this is IT security, but we should be careful not to be too quick to flag as Offtopic questions or answers which end up in the People or Process areas.

Comment: of course not. Au contraire, the mass of questions is already tipped a bit too heavy in the direction of technical. The original question came from the silent merging with other SE proposals. For more updated discussion, see http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/16/33. Again, not a problem of people/process, but of non-professional security.

Comment: Cheers AviD - understood :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about "Corporate Security", "Fedral Security", or some variation of those?

Comment: Those are both quite exclusive, really. I'm an app security guy who doesn't work for a corporation or the feds, where would I fit? :)