# Why are we security.stackexchange.com instead of itsecurity.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

I'm hoping this question was answered before the domain was made.  But, for those of us who weren't around then, what drove the decision in the way that it went?  Why aren't we itsecurity.stackexchange.com or it-security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Good question. I have wondered about this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that was Jeff's arbitrary decision when he merged a few different security-related proposals into one site. But what's wrong with 'security'? It's easier to spell than itsecurity ;-).

Comment: Just plain "Security" is a little *too* general.  It implies that this site also might include topics on physical security devices, security guards, home security, etc.  Some of these may be somewhat relevant to our community (if so, just barely), and others are quite clearly not.  I'm suggesting that Security.SE should have been left reserved for another, more general proposal - or one that focuses on more traditional, everyday security topics.  A proposal such as this one:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4729/security

Comment: It should also be noted that merging with the proposal that *should* have Security.SE has been discussed here already:  http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/28/merge-with-the-security-proposal

Comment: @Iszi: Yeah, but it's only a temporary thing while we're in beta.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't around then either, so @AviD or @GrahamLee will have a better view, but I have seen a range of conversations, and [these](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/485) two [questions](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/485)

I am pretty glad it wasn't just IT Security, as it is so interconnected with the wider Information Security field that to take it in isolation would leave you without a realistic view of risk and threats.

Comment: Actually I don't :). I think probably because it was the common denominator between the different site proposals that were merged here. Also as far as SEO goes, I dont think anyone searches for "IT security", just "security". The IT part, in my mind, is to differentiate between the whole private-user/home-system etc discussion. When the site launches, we'd probably have the option to change the domain name, even to one that is not a subdomain of SE.